# lodash where method to consider nested array elements

Tags: javascript, lodash

[lodash where](https://lodash.com/docs#where) method is not considering nested array elements when searching. Consider the below example:

```
var foo = [
  {
    "id": "123",
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": "1231",
        "name": "foo1"
      },
      {
        "id": "1232",
        "name": "bar1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "4561",
        "name": "foo2"
      },
      {
        "id": "4562",
        "name": "bar2"
      }
    ]
  }
]

_.where(foo, { 'id' : '123' } ) //works and returns the element
_.where(foo, { 'id' : '1231' } ) //fails.. trying to match the first element in the elements array. does not return matched element
```

Is there an API in lodash or other JavaScript library to perform deep search?

Comment: It cannot know the structure of your object. Using `_.where(foo, {'elements': [{ 'id' : '1231' }]} )` will work. (*it will return the top level that contains it*)

Comment: above is simplified scenario of actual issue at hand. In my case "key" `elements` is not constants. It could be "elements", "items", "things" etc and it will be nested deep. 3rd, 4th , 5th level .... Only constant part is "id" key

Comment: and what do you want returned ? the top level object that contains it or the final object that has that property/value combo ?

Comment: @Gaby the final object.

Comment: I closed the question. The answer there, works as-is for lodash as well.